# Not getting Data from JSON Call

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have created for learning purposes a small application wiche should take data from a JSON file and the display it in a tableview.

I am not correctly sure how to access my data from the JSON. Would be more then glad if some could help me.

```
[
  {
    "title": "dolore laboris ea adipisicing",
    "description": "Ullamco adipisicing aute deserunt id do eu aliqua deserunt deserunt quis elit. Irure excepteur aliquip mollit tempor. Minim est nisi aute do tempor nisi aliquip pariatur. Laboris qui duis consequat magna qui. Proident nisi duis Lorem officia eiusmod exercitation aliqua dolore sunt esse sunt consectetur ut.",
    "images": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "title": "laborum minim deserunt elit",
        "pubDate": 1421120486130,
        "picture": "http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nightlife/",
        "caption": "deserunt proident cillum laboris duis ut minim est"
      },
```

This is my JSON file i want to access the properties title as well as picture.

What I am doing:

I have Parser class to access the JSON

constant with the base url

a function wiche is making the call

```
    func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
        let route = baseURL
        makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
    }

and a normal **makeHTTPGetRequest** function.


And this is how i try to fill my table 

    func addDummyData() {
        RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableViewData { json in
        let results = json["images"]
            for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
                let user: AnyObject = subJson["images"].object
                self.items.addObject(user)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    tableView?.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        }

        let user:JSON =  JSON(self.items[indexPath.row])

        let picURL = user["picture"].string
        let url = NSURL(string: picURL!)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        cell!.textLabel?.text = user["title"].string
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)


        return cell!
    }
```

With not much success .. I am not getting anything back

How I try to call the data

```
func getTableViewData(onCompletion:(JSON) -> Void){
        let route = baseURL
        makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Post the code for `RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableViewData { json in` it seems that is where the problem is as you mentioned it is not returning any data.

Comment: Can you rather post this function `RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableViewData` if its not returning data it means there is an issue there.

Comment: Is the `makeHTTPGetRequest` getting the json result back? If not `println` that `err`

Comment: @sbarow Yes i am receiving  the JSON data

Comment: @sbarow  I still think that we are not correctly accessing the JSON file in this function func addDummyData() {

Comment: If you log the result of that call what do you get? i.e. `println(json)`

Comment: @sbarow getting back the complete json file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81374/discussion-between-sbarow-and-mingebag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using the SwiftyJSON class to process the JSON string.

Here a solution assuming the following :

- a variable with this declaration

  ```
  var items : [JSON]()
  ```
- The function `RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableViewData` returns SwiftyJSON compatible data
- The returned SwiftyJSON object is **one** Dictionary, which contains an Array `images` containing a few properties

The function `addDummyData` iterates thru the array of images and adds the JSON.dictionaries objects to `items`

```
  func addDummyData() {
    RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableViewData { json in
      let results = json["images"]
      for (index: String, user: JSON) in results {
        items.append(user)
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        tableView?.reloadData()
      })
    }
  }
```

The function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` creates the cells as usual and assignes the properties `title` and  `picture` to the appropriate cell properties.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }

    let user = items[indexPath.row]

    if let picURL = user["picture"].string, url = NSURL(string: picURL) {
      if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
      }
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = user["title"].string

    return cell!
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for help but there the problem that this function func tableView(tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{ is never getting called

Comment: is `reloadData()` called? Write `tableView!.reloadData()` so check that the table view is not nil

Comment: `reloadData()` is called

Comment: btw I had some problem declaring this variable `var items : [JSON]()` had to do this`?var items :[JSON] = []`

Comment: then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is supposed to be called, too. Insert `println()` lines for example  `println(user)` to see the user data. If the user data is empty, nothing will be displayed

Comment: C.user  this is the result that i get back if i println(user)

Comment: then the method is called but the data structure of `user` does not match the  assumption that it has properties `picture` and `title`. Do your really use SwiftyJSON? Could you post a link where the json data is from, if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82173/discussion-between-mingebag-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is returning an array, so you need to iterate through the array to access its items.

```
func addDummyData() {
    RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableViewData { json in
    // Iterate through the JSON response array
    for results in json {
     // You can now use the results objects to get "images" etc objects from the json.
    }
}
```

Comment: (String,JSON) does not have a member named subscript is the error that i get now